# Firefox < 42 bug? 'display: block' elements float when paired with a sibling 'float: left' element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

While working with a client I experienced a very specific issue which is only visible in Firefox below version 42.
Basically, using the standard Bootstrap way to add a form group with a label and an input field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

and adding a float: left to the label

```
label {
  float: left;
}
```

would make the input field float up to the same line as the label, but only in Firefox < 42. In the newer versions it would still be displayed on a new line. Chrome/Safari also renders them on separate lines so that seems to be the intended behavior (meaning that there's a bug below FF 42).

[Codepen with example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWvXWG) (issue only visible in FF 41 and lower)

Is this a bug in Firefox?
If so, what's causing the bug specifically (i.e. not what's causing it in the FF source code, but which specific css rules are clashing/broken).

I thought floats and display where pretty old-school stuff and I assumed that this would be working in pretty much all modern versions of Chrome/Firefox/Safari, so for me this is a bit of a surprise. Out of pure curiosity, is there a list of bugs for these common/old types of css properties?

Example screenshot:

[image: Example from Firefox v36]